# Charging tablet while in OTG

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, battery

Similar questions have been asked before, but the posts are years old and not really answered.

So:

I have a tablet with USB-C or Lightning port (female). I want to connect a special 5G receiver and a power bank at the same time.

The receiver is a Insta360 Farsight device with Micro USB port (female). I think it's some OTG stuff, but I'm not sure. Alternative, there is also a LAN port which can be used - I have a LAN to USB-adapter.
The power bank is pretty simple and has some USB-A ports as well as a Micro USB and a USB-C port (all female).

I thought a y-cable will fulfill this task, but this application seems to be very unusual, yet so obviously.

Reading the other post and searching the web, I found such a device:
https://lavaaccessory.com/products/simulcharge-tablet-adapters-tl-002/

But I wonder, if there is an other option - using y-cables or USB hub and adapters?

Thank you for your help!

*Martin

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody will find this helpful:

Using a USB-C OTG hub is working.
My final setup is a Samsung Tab S5e along with YXwin USB C Hub. The farsight receiver is connected via ethernet cable to the hub, as well as the power bank. The hub is connected to the tablet and now I can use the camera control app with live preview, while the tablet gets power from the power bank.

*Martin